# php, smarty, extends -> __construct

Tags: php

В общем оборачиваю смарти в свой класс:

```
require(ENGINE.'/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php');
class EEE extends Smarty {
    private $templ;
    public function __construct($templ) {

        $this->Smarty();
        $this->template_dir = ENGINE.'/templ/';
        $this->compile_dir  = ENGINE.'/compile_templ/';
        $this->config_dir   = ENGINE.'/';
        $this->cache_dir    = ENGINE.'/cache_templ/';
        $this->caching = true;

        $this->templ = $templ;
    }
    public function view() {
        $this->display($this->templ);
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'PHP5 requires you to call __construct() instead of Smarty()'...
```

Как верно построить класс, чтобы можно было вызвать вида:

```
$template = new EEE(ENGINE. '/templ/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С смарти дела не имел, но возможно как-то так:

замените

```
  $this->Smarty();
```

на

```
  parrent::__construct();
```

Comment: да я экстрасенс ^.^

Answer (score 1):

ага тоже хрень была такая!
мозжечком понимаю что судя по тому что пишет ошибка:

> PHP5 requires you to call
> __construct() instead of Smarty()

нужно вместо:

```
$this->Smarty();
```

подставить:

```
parent::__construct();
```

а когда стал думать не только мозжечком поковырял код Smarty и понял что нужно

```
parent::__construct($this);
```

кстати вопросик: выложил бы сразу функцию для передачи переменых смарти и развертывания оного =) думаю новичкам как я было бы полезно =).